# Export gif in photoshop - fps or frame delay ignored

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I import an .avi video as layers in photoshop 2020.
I enable "Limit to every 2 frames". It was a 30fps video... when loaded the delay between each frame is 0.03  (if I skipped two shouldn't it be 15?).

Even when I open the video editor and set the fps to anything else, playing looks the same. It is speedup to be smooth and doesn't respect the delays I set in the animation frames view.

Exporting ignores that speed, not only in the windows preview, but when uploading in the server. Delay is ignored, and it is played smooth and very fast.

I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame delay in GIFs is measured in seconds, not fps. 0.03 seconds equates to approx 33 frames per second. (100/3). All you need to do is change it to 0.06 to make the delay longer.

Note however that changing the delay on a GIF might not always make an appreciable difference, since the playback speed a gif displays at on the web depends on several additional factors, such as the viewer's web browser, and speed of their computer. There's no guarantee every viewer on the web will be able to see a GIF at the exact delay you set.

When you say you are uploading to a server, how are you doing that? Is it through some website?  There may be some processing going on that you are not aware of. If so, not sure that we can really help with that particular problem.

What I can say is that if you click and drag a GIF file into your web browser, and it plays back at the speed your expect, then the fault doesn't lie with Photoshop.

Comment: Thanks!   I tried 0.06, and you are right. Setting "skip every 2 frames" will make my video faster and the delay between frames will not be kept. That's confusing but I understood how this works.
With the server I mean, a hosting service, no postprocessing was happening. 
About the speed at which gifs run, yes! I just wanted it to play slower, similar to the original video.